# Can time-invariant variables cause autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation, random-effects-model, pooling

I am running a pooled OLS regression and Random effects regression.

I have tested for autocorrelation for both methods. In the pooled OLS model I find serial correlation but for the RE model I find no serial correlation.

How is this possible? Is it possible that the unobserved time invariant variables that are removed in RE model are causing serial correlation in the pooled OLS regression?

Comment: What exactly did you test for? Autocorrelation in what variable? Or in residuals? Or something else? And what exactly were the result?

Comment: I tested for autocorrelation in the residuals. I thought that when talking about autocorrelation, it is always autocrrelation in the residuals? For pooled OLS the p-value is 0 which Means I rejected the null hypothesis which says that there is no autocorrelation. For RE I used xtserial command in Stata and I cannot reject the null hypothesis saying that there is no autocorrelation.

Comment: I am not sure if autocorrelation is always on the residuals; I think responses can also be autocorrelated.